# How to stop Ajax call inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The function `newMessage()` is only called when the user presses the submit button or presses enter. The problem is that the AJAX script keeps calling inside, even when `newMessage()` is not called. For example if I type anything on the `input` field without even hitting the submit, the value would be passed by AJAX.

I can't seem to understand how to stop this, any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```html
<div class="message-input">
  <div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Write your message..." />
    <i class="fa fa-paperclip attachment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <input type="hidden" value="0" name="convo_id" id="convo_id" readonly/>
    <button class="submit">
      <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
function newMessage() {
  message = $(".message-input input").val();
  if ($.trim(message) == '') {
    return false;
  }
  var convo_id = document.getElementById("convo_id").value;
  var msg = $('#msg').val();
  $.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: 'send_chat.php',
    data: ({
      convo_id: convo_id,
      msg: msg
    }),
    success: function(data) {
    }
  });
};

$('.submit').click(function() {
  newMessage();
});

$(window).on('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    newMessage();
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: This question is not java related.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Abort Ajax requests using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Comment: So, you want to fire that event for any `input` field or only for `convo_id`. Right?

Answer (score 3):

jQuery Ajax method return an XHR object. That object contains abort method. You can use that link as follows

```
var xhr=jQuery.ajax({
        });
```

Now you can use abort method. which will kill the request

```
xhr.abort();
```